# How do I deploy my transaction to the eth network? I used my system terminal with the infura main net but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, web3js

This is the code, how do I deploy it to the eth main network? I am using web3. Is there more packages to be installed aside web3, eutherum-js? Please I need help to proceed thanks so much.

```
const TX = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction

let Web3 = require('web3')
let url ='HTTPs://mainnet.infura.io/api'


let web3 = new  Web3(url)

function intervalFunc(){
  const account1 ='0x2c68F246aBDD28C20c06106E6bf001B79f5dF541'
  const private = Buffer.from('24a684dbbcb9496603c570e1de2289248762110154c69ebe4ffb0ec0f20a1d2d','hex',)
  const privatekey = new Uint8Array((private ))
  console.log(privatekey)
  const account2 = '0xc470268A14016fC3615b5dB4AF5797CF9D8E43dc'


web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (error,txCount)=>{
  // build a transation object

  const txObject  ={
    'nonce':web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    'to': account2,
    'value': web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('2200000', 'gwei')),
    //'gasLimit':web3.utils.toHex(21000),
    'gas': 3141592,      //web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
  }
  console.log(txObject)

  //sign transaction with private key of sender

  const tx = new TX(txObject)
  tx.sign(privatekey)

  //serialize the transaction

const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

  //broadcast transaction to the network

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (error,txHash) =>{
    console.log(txHash)
  })
})
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate on "doesn't seem to work". Does it print an error message? If yes, what is the error message. Or does it just run the script without any output? How do you run the script in your terminal? What does your config look like (redact any sensitive data such as private key)? ... With the information you provided, it's not possible to reproduce your issue (and look for its cause).

Comment: FYI your question shares a private key and a corresponding address. This address doesn't hold any funds on mainnet (possibly this is the cause of your issue - not being able to cover the transaction fees from an empty account), but overall it's unwise to share your private key unless it's a key generated specifically for testing purposes and relevant to the question.

Comment: Those are my local host keys not mine.

Comment: The code doesn't print error but it doesn't carry out it function on the net.

Comment: I want to make a transaction that transfer my eth from my working wallet to my wallet everytime automatically with 5 sec interval

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't print any output, because the `intervalFunc()` function is never called. If you want to call it every 5 seconds (as your comment states), you can use `setInterval()` for example.

```
function intervalFunc() {
    // your current implementation
}

setInterval('intervalFunc', 5000); // calls the function every 5000 ms
```

Then it's going to try to send ETH from the `account1` address to the `account2` address using a mainnet provider. Which means, it's going to try to send the funds from a mainnet address - to a mainnet address.

**Because of the way how Ethereum networks are designed, it's not possible to trasfer funds between separate networks (e.g. your local network and mainnet).**

If you want to transfer funds between both addresses on the local networks, you'll need to use your local web3 provider. Its address depends on the network emulator that you're using, but most likely it's going to be `http://127.0.0.1:7545` or `http://127.0.0.1:8545`.

*Note: Your mainnet provider url (`HTTPs://mainnet.infura.io/api`) is also incorrect, but I'm not sure whether it's written this way in your original code or if you redacted the token. Usual Infura mainnet provider URL is `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<projectId>`, where `<projectId>` is 32 hex characters assigned by Infura.*

Comment: I also included the setInterval functions. It works well on my local host using node project.js.  it doesn't send eth when connected to a infura main network. I dot know what is missing In the code. Do I need to use truffle init for this? Kindly assist me

Comment: I have added that, it only works on the local machine. I use node project.js to initiate it. How can I deploy it to the main network

Comment: @John To use the script on mainnet, you need to pass the correct provider URL (in your case the provider is Infura) - see the last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: I have a project on infura which I have used. I then used node project.js on my terminal. Am I meant to use node command on my terminal with infura url as the main net?